# iOS: TableView inside TableView cell not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview inside a tableview cell. I am unable scroll that table. I have also attached the screenshot of the table Here is my code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString 
   *)reuseIdentifier
 {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
    self.subMenuTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.subMenuTableView.tag = 100;
    self.subMenuTableView.delegate = self;
    self.subMenuTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.subMenuTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.subMenuTableView.bounces = NO;
    self.subMenuTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    self.subMenuTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    [self addSubview:self.subMenuTableView]; // add it cell
}
return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];
//UITableView *subMenuTableView =(UITableView *) [self viewWithTag:100];
self.subMenuTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.3, self.bounds.size.width-5,    self.bounds.size.height-5);//set the frames for tableview
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you need multiple tableviews for this? Can't you just use sections to divide your tableView.

Comment: It is not recommended to use in this way, I suggest using tableview's sections and headers to do it ,if it does not fit, maybe UICollectionView will be a good choice.